# Make incoming requests execute serially in NodeJS(express)

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on a token booking system for a hospital and am using MongoDB atlas as the database. Due to the network latency, concurrent requests are causing some trouble. So I am trying to make the requests execute serially to avoid any booking being saved with the same time slot.

This is my requirement:

Say, my incoming request body is of the form:

```
{
  ...
  "depatmentID":"dept1",
  ...
}
```

Basically what happens when a request comes is given below:

```
DepartmentDetails.findOne({department: departmentID}).then((department) => {
    /* 
    1. fetch department details
    2. update some of the fields like : 
       incrementing total number of tokens booked, last token time slot etc..

    (there are some other computations as well)

    3. now update the details in MongoDB
    */
    DepartmentDetails.findOneAndUpdate({department: departmentID}, dataToUpdate).then((data) => {
        //4. send response
    })
})
```

**For all the (concurrent) requests having same `departmentID`, I need to execute the route function serially**. I have tried various methods and nothing worked.

Please do help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using optimistic locking instead of executing requests sequentially? Possibly like this: https://jimmybogard.com/document-level-optimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb/?

Comment: I guess you want to do this on HTTP layer, not database. It's not easy to do as you need to maintain a stateful queue across requests, while Express middlewares typically work per request. If you don't have time to build your own solution, find a library that does this for you like [Express request queue](https://github.com/jeescu/express-request-queue).

Comment: Okay. Let me try this. Thank you.

Comment: You could also solve this by processing the requests through a NodeJS `streams` pipeline. The streams module will then act as an Async queue. Ie: 1) an incoming request executes your api handler. 2) the api handler calls write() on a stream.Writable and awaits the write to be executed. 3) the writable does the DB operations